# What is the opposite of "steep"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

In rock-climbing, we describe an incline as "steep" (which is anything from 90 degrees to overhanging) but we don't have a good word to mean "not steep".  At least I've never heard anyone use one; instead people use convoluted phrases like "not too steep".

I looked at the [“opposite for 'steep learning curve'”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6212/whats-the-opposite-for-steep-learning-curve) post, but none of those suggestions really seems to fit here.

**Edit:** I asked a rock-climbing English major and she said that "low-angle" and "slabby" were most often used for cliffs in the 50-90 degree range.

Comment: *Downhill* isn't what you're looking for, is it? ;)

Comment: You can still have a steep downhill though @muntoo

Comment: Anything more than about 45 degrees would be *steep* enough for a pedestrian to navigate. Many answers seem to be in regards to amounts less than maybe 30 degrees. But in your example, an incline on the order of 75 degrees would not be steep?

Comment: *Steep* is a quantifying adjective and therefore has no "opposite". Don't certain climbs have difficultly numbers for exactly this purpose: to quantify the steepness of the slope? I'd suggest *a low rise*, but that's something you can walk up.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'd say *shallow* or *gentle* are suitable...

Comment: I wouldn't -1 this but, to me, "shallow" implies a negative incline (i.e., that I am observing the incline from the higher end, though I can't articulate a concrete reason). I say a "shallow bowl" for example, because I observe the bowl from outside the high edge (or, perhaps, because it's concave).

Comment: I think "gentle" always works (gentle incline, gentle decline, gentle slope, gentle ascent, gentle descent), but "shallow" only really works for descents (shallow decline, shallow descent) due to the concave connotations that msanford pointed out.

Comment: While I agree it might fit, I don't like shallow as an opposite of steep!

Comment: @msanford - I'd tend to agree, so I'd prefer `gentle` for that reason; but if you said shallow, people would get the drift anyway - which is the whole point of communication. ;)

Comment: Neither shallow nor gentle are the opposite of steep, but rather words we make do with because there is no actual word for what we mean; when asked the opposite of gentle or shallow we wouldn't naturally say steep, but harsh or deep respectively. Is there a general name for the situation where words 'should' exist but don't, and we have to make do with others?

Comment: Shallow is the opposite of deep.

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps one of these?

- Flat
- Gentle

If a noun works for your usage, you could go with *glacis* which means "gentle slope"

Comment: Thesaurus says "gentle" as well (about cliffs), so I think you got it. About "a steep increase", so something in general, it says "gradual", just saying.

Comment: +1 Indeed, I say "a steep mountain face" and "a gentle hill".

Comment: In french (especially for bicycle riders) we have this phrase: "un faux plat" meaning "a treacherously not so horizontal road section".

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest you can call it "a *gradual* incline."

Comment: To me that means a change in incline.

Answer (score 4):

In the context of inclines, I suggest that 'slight' is most commonly used as the opposite of steep.

Answer (score 2):

*Steep* is also used in reference to learning curves or ramp-ups that are difficult. In that context, or in the context of a hill or a rock to climb, some of the opposites suggested so far (*gentle*, *gradual*) make sense, as do *simple*, *easy* or *comfortable*.

Answer (score 2):

As a climber, caver, and geoscientist, the lack of a commonly-used antonym for "steep" is a constant frustration! No appropriate word exists and frankly it's a big gaping hole in the English language.

In geoscience, we use "**low-angle**" to refer to an outcrop or formation that is not steeply dipping (read about [strike and dip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strike_and_dip) for more on this). There is an entire field of study devoted to the mysterious mechanics of low-angle normal faults. You do hear people saying "gradual" as well but then people often think you're referring to a change in slope.

I've begun (mis)using "**positive**" for the climbing application, and people know what I mean. In climbing, a "positive hold" is one with a slope that makes it useful. (As in "yeah man those bomber huecos are super positive") By analogy, I like to say that a cliff that slopes forwards as it goes up (what the OP referred to as less than 90 degrees) is a "positive" wall whereas an overhanging wall feels "negative." In climbing we often use "steep" to mean overhanging, or extremely overhanging. So, I've been using "steep" versus "positive" to refer to the angle of the wall when climbing and people seem to know what I mean.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

In the context indicated (hills), I find that the opposite of steep is most clearly expressed in the form of two-word phrase using one of the words already mentioned in previous answers, plus the word sloping, such as **gently sloping**, or **gradually sloping**.

Answer (score 1):

Although *gentle* works, it usually connotes a descent. A great choice for this, especially as it relates to climbing (ascent), is **easy**.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the word declining, descent or maybe recession.

> The hill is declining.
>   We began our descent.

or

> We shall now begin our trek on the
>   declining hill.

Comment: The poster was not asking for the opposite of incline, but rather the opposite of steeply sloping, regardless of direction.