# Is there a single word meaning 'to grow and flourish'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can anybody tell me if there a  single word which has the meaning 'to grow and flourish'?

Comment: Literally? Metaphorically?

Comment: I think _growish_ is a nice word.

Comment: 'Prosper' might serve.

Comment: Have you looked in an online thesaurus for 'grow' or 'flourish'?

Comment: Yes, @BarrieEngland - Live long and prosper

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [*thrive*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thrive).

Answer (score 4):

How about *bloom* / *blossom* ?

Comment: *Bloom/blossom* usually imply a "metamorphosis" into a more pleasing form, but OP's *grow and flourish* suggest he's looking more for the *thrive* connotations.

Answer (score 3):

**Flourish**

> 1. to be in a vigorous state; thrive: a period in which art flourished.
> 2. to be in its or in one's prime; be at the height of fame, excellence, influence, etc.
> 3. to be successful; prosper.
> 4. to grow luxuriantly, or thrive in growth, as a plant.

Comment: I think that's a bit of a sly answer. You might as well have suggested OP's other word - **grow**.

Comment: I see your point, but he's looking for a single word, it just so happens that he already has it.

Comment: Indubitably. So I should be justified in putting up "grow" to collect a bit more rep! Seriously, I think *flourish* truly is the best word from OP's point of view. He knows the word, and it means what he wants to say, which are seriously good reasons for using words. But *thrive* has all that and more (not least, alliteration with "thrust"), so - no disrespect - I hope you don't mind if I cast my vote for "Ma Man" @tenfour. (I'm confident your day will come! :)

Comment: ...Just to say that @tenfour had another well-deserved hit with [clunky](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24471/is-there-another-way-of-saying-user-unfriendly/24475#24475), though I really wish he'd go back there and delete the totally worthless "unintuitive".

Comment: It's cool, I voted up thrive as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Evolve**

It kind of sounds scientific but I don't think it is inartistic as a word, if that is what you are going for.

or

**Mature**

I think it is pretty acceptable to think that as time passes by certain tastes of our mature and become more refine.

Although, I am not sure if any of these words really cover the 'flourish' part of your requirements.