# Is there a verb that describes the act of being healthy?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb that describes the act of being healthy (exercising, eating well, etc.)? Preferably a single word

Comment: Being healthy is not an act, it's a condition.  Doing things that (supposedly) promote good health expresses an interest in physical fitness.  Unfortunately for you, two words.

Comment: I am healthing all the time since I high-blood-pressured.

Comment: @Mitch — Well I hope you cover your mouth while doing so.

Comment: Answered at [Is there a single word meaning 'to grow and flourish'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51940/is-there-a-single-word-meaning-to-grow-and-flourish).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think 'thriving' is the closest I can get.

> If someone or something thrives, they do well and are successful, healthy, or strong.

([Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thrive))

Comment: @ sumelic My mistake. Your edit accepted.

Comment: In the US, doctors often use "thrive" for this concept. "Failure to thrive" is a commonly cited reason that summarizes why a patient, especially a very young child or an elderly individual, has required a medical evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [flourish](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flourish): (ODO)

> [no object] (of a living organism) grow or develop in a healthy or vigorous way, especially as the result of a particularly congenial environment.
>
> ‘wild plants flourish on the banks of the lake’

In Taylor's [Health and Human Flourishing](https://books.google.com/books?id=pGEgriGjWo8C&pg=PA35&dq=flourished&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip2MGq6NLWAhWCyyYKHRTVBko4MhDoAQhJMAY#v=onepage&q=flourish&f=false):

> It is clear then, that our flourishing is subject to the vicissitudes of fortune, to disease and disability, to the powers of nature, and to the choices and conduct of others.