# Can we use "use unfriendly" as an adjective?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, word-usage

I was wondering according to American English if this is a valid grammatical sentence:

> This item is a little use unfriendly.

It sounds *ok* but I was wondering if "use unfriendly" (I mean without the 'r', **not** user-unfriendly) could be used as an adjective this way.

P.S. I was wondering if it is grammatical according to British English too.

Comment: Do you mean [user-unfriendly](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24471/is-there-another-way-of-saying-user-unfriendly)?

Comment: @Danielδ uh no, i mean "use unfriendly" or "use-unfriendly"

Comment: What is the difference in meaning between *user-unfiendly* and *use-unfriendly*?

Comment: @Danielδ sometimes depending on the phrasing of the entire sentence / paragraph, one may *sound* better than the other, so now I know I can choose which to use because both are grammatical

Comment: As I understand English, *use unfriendly* is not a grammatical adjective.  It doesn't [obey the rules of grammar](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) and it doesn't [conform to standard usage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grammatical).

Comment: Too localised. Native speakers do *not* use this expression, so why is OP asking if *he* can use it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers by native speakers do you mean American English or British English?

Comment: @Pacerier: Oh gosh! Don't tell me Americans habitually say it!

Comment: ...I've just been to the trouble of checking every one of about 100 consecutive occurences of **use unfriendly** indexed by [Google Books](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22use+unfriendly%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22use+unfriendly%22&pbx=1&oq=%22use+unfriendly%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l0l91337l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=c74deb9746404bf2&biw=1434&bih=836). In every single case, it's just the ordinary usage where "use" is a verb. I stand by my closevote.

Comment: I'll go out on limb and speak for all varieties of English but Indian (AmE, BrE, IrE, AusE, etc), and say that even if there are logical rules that might allow 'use unfriendly' it is very grating, sounds like a non-native neologism, everybody would cringe and wonder why you didn't say the perfectly acceptable 'user-unfriendly'.

Comment: Just to add a point to what others have said: "user-friendly" is a commonly used and accepted term with a well-understood meaning. There is no point in trying to create a new term, "use-friendly", that as far as I can tell from your post would just be synonym for "user-friendly" except that it would be unfamiliar. Don't try to create new words when there's already a perfectly good existing word. And especially in this case, where it's just one letter different, 99.9% of readers would take it as a mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean by "use unfriendly" *unfriendly to use*, then you [need a hyphen](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word/34766#34766), or the sentence is hard to parse and read and [ungrammatical](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grammatical).  Also, *unfriendly to **user*** would be a more conventional way to describe such an item, hence *user-unfriendly*.  The latter would be a better choice semantically and grammatically.  *Not user-friendly* would probably be more popular than *user-unfriendly*, and [this EL&U post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24471/is-there-another-way-of-saying-user-unfriendly) gives several more options to replace it, too, if you're still not comfortable using it.

Comment: So you are saying that Kris is (absolutely) wrong?

Comment: Yes.  I guess s/he must be using a different definition of *grammatical*.

Comment: @Danielδ: You have conveniently overlooked the part "I presume you mean **user** -unfriendly." in my answer. You were talking about **use unfriendly** instead.

Comment: @Danielδ I don't get it, regardless of style, it's either grammatical or its not right?

Comment: @Kris Well, the OP asked whether *use unfriendly* was grammatical.  You began your answer saying "Yes. Grammatically, it would be correct." That's what I am disagreeing with.  Yes, the OP did mean *user-unfriendly*, but that's not what he was asking about.

Comment: @Pacerier: You are correct, and in this case, *use unfriendly* is not grammatical.  I assumed Kris had thought *grammatical* means something other than its real meaning, and had therefore erroneously called *use unfriendly* grammatical.  Turns out s/he may have been saying something else; I'm not yet sure what it is.

Comment: @Danielδ: Did you not mean *need a hyphen* in your first link? The rest looks good to me - daft question though, IMHO, so I'm sticking to my new *cruel but fair* policy of not upvoting even correct answers to questions I think should be closed. A brief comment could have set OP on the path to righteous language usage.

Comment: @Pacerier: "It's either grammatical or it's not": unfortunately for automatic grammar checkers, it's kinda gray. Most things are not gray: "I are" is always wrong. But some...there's a question (it's OK for some people but not for others; it's not OK when talking to the queen but OK with your friends). Then there's the case (such as this one) where one might be able to give a logical justification for correctness (I don't think you can here), but it still sounds very grating.

Comment: @Mitch But of course when someone ask if it is a "valid grammatical sentence", it obviously means **standard English** isn't it?

Comment: @Pacerier: "Use unfriendly" is always ungrammatical, as applying *friendly* to the wrong type of noun. "User unfriendly" may or may not be acceptable (because *user friendly* is idiomatic in the computer field, though not strictly meaningful).  Please edit question to make clear which you are asking about (before a flamewar breaks out...)

Comment: @TimLymington Please elaborate on your first statement. How is "use" the wrong type of noun?

Comment: @Pacerier: 'obviously' yes, in school contexts but not here at ELU. When you're really sick, do you go '[to the hospital](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+the+hospital%2Cto+hospital&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)' or '[to hospital](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+the+hospital%2Cto+hospital&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3)'? Both are grammatical for particular varieties (and the other one not at all).

Comment: @Mitch But I explicitly stated the context is American English in the question itself

Comment: @TimLymington as per your request

Comment: @Pacerier: Sorry, I'm mixing too many message. RE standard English: there are many, so here at ELU you can't assume in general what is the standard. Re: grammatical: there's logic and there's how it sounds, and 'sounds' wins. **Exec summary: Don't use 'use-unfriendly', use 'user-unfriendly'.**

Comment: @Pacerier isn't that exactly what my answer says?

Answer (score 0):

Using a hyphen between *user* and *unfriendly* makes it more readable:

> **user-unfriendly**

Comment: Is a hyphen allowed between `use` and `unfriendly` ? : use-unfriendly

Comment: @Pacerier, Yes, you can use hyphen or if you like you can use "less user-friendly" as Kris suggested.

Comment: @Pacerier,   "user-friendly" not "use-friendly"

Answer (score 0):

How about "this item is [***user-hostile***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/user-hostile)", which Wiktionary defines as "Difficult to use, especially for an untrained user."?

Answer (score -2):

Here is a kind of answer from a student of ancient Greek (me!). You can say that it is a kind of abbreviation (from 'unfriendly  user').  So it involves ellipsis (leaving something out, which has to be 'understood' by the reader/hearer.  It looks, as it stands, somewhat germanic, and I am tempted to say that it should therefore be written as a single word ('userunfriendly').  But that violates an embedded sense of how things should look (and sound) in English.  As I have left it, the word 'user' functions as what in logic is called a 'predicate modifier' (something that changes the meaning of a predicate {adjective}). This is interesting, because, whereas in the past these things would eventually be settled by the emergence of authoritative dictionaries/grammars by specialists giving names to phenomena such as this, this is no longer how it happens.

Comment: The OP is asking about *use unfriendly*; is that the phrase you're talking about?

Answer (score -3):

Yes.

Grammatically, it would be correct. However, you may want to rephrase it as: *This item is a little **less user-friendly***. [I presume you mean **user** -unfriendly.]

[un·friend·ly](https://www.google.com/?q=define%3aunfriendly)/ˌənˈfren(d)lē/
Adjective:
Not friendly: "she shot him an unfriendly glance"; "environmentally unfriendly activities".
Synonyms:
hostile - inimical - unkind - adverse - unfavourable

Comment: By your definition of "grammatically correct", it would appear that *any* combination of noun+adjective is valid. It doesn't even make much sense semantically - how can something be "unfriendly" towards "use"? Is it therefore valid to say short trousers are "winter unfriendly"? ELU is supposed to be concerned with *English as she is spoke* - which may not be exactly grammatical, but at least that one does occur.

Comment: @Fumble: You make a good point, but the example 'winter unfriendly' actually does sound OK. Are there examples of noun + adjective that are definitely not allowed?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think you mean, "English as she bees done spoke". :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers How can something be "unfriendly" towards "use"? The same way something can be "incompatible" with "use".

Comment: @MetaEd: You're stretching "meaning" to its limits. Sure, it's semantically and grammatically okay (if a tad mundane) to say a chocolate teapot is **incompatible** *with its* **use** *as a vessel for serving hot tea*, but would anyone honestly say *"This teapot is use-incompatible"*? I think you're just being vexatious, to be honest.

Comment: For one, note that I was referring to *use **r-** unfriendly*, not *use unfriendly*. As for grammar, everything else in grammar is in black-and-white, semantics is subjective. @FumbleFingers I understand your sentiment, but I'm fine with the semantic validity of *user-unfriendly*.

Comment: If someone had down voted on the mistaken presumption that I was referring to *use unfriendly* rather than *use **r** unfriendly*, I must ask them to read my answer once again. Else I feel the down votes on that false premise would amount to cheating. Regarding diverting the attention from the real question of 'friendly' vs. 'unfriendly', the over-enthusiasm is clearly unwarranted.

Comment: @Kris: I don't want to seem pedantic (particularly in light of my earlier comment to MetaEd), but I was one of those who downvoted. Partly because I don't much care for the "grammatically correct" line, and telling OP that *"Yes, he can (reasonably?) say 'use-unfriendly'"*. But mainly because OP specifically said he was **not** asking about *"user-unfriendly"* - so whether what you say is "correct" or not (and I don't care for the usage myself), it's simply inappropriate to post an answer based on making the switch from **use-** to **user-**.