# An antonym for "usability"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there another way of saying 'user-unfriendly'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24471/is-there-another-way-of-saying-user-unfriendly)

Regarding the usability of some sort of system (whether soft- or hardware), what would be a good (and established!) word to express that something lacks usability. The best I could come up with was "non-usability" but I believe there existed an actual antonym.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: None of the suggestions there seems to apply. Do they?

Comment: I'm not with you. If you want a noun defining the quintessential attribute of a [Chocolate Teapot](http://www.plokta.com/plokta/issue23/teapot.htm), I'd suggest **uselessness**. Otherwise, surely what you're talking about is things being *difficult to use*, in which case I'd have thought by definition that's because they aren't "user-friendly".

Comment: ...there are obviously words like *unusability* and *inutility*, but these are a bit ugly, imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the answers to the question [Is there another way of saying 'user-unfriendly'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24471/is-there-another-way-of-saying-user-unfriendly), convert them into nouns, and take your pick:

- high learning curve
- user-hostility
- unintuitiveness
- clunkiness
- unwieldiness
- inaccessibility
- awkwardness
- frustration
- unfriendliness
- cludginess
- confusion
- Windows ;)
- Lotus Notes ;)
- bureaucracy
- unusability
- opacity
- obtuseness
- crypticness
- lousiness

Comment: +1 for Windows, but I'll probably go with *unusability* ...