# Is it correct to say "The learning curve has always been uphill"?

Tags: word-usage

A quick google search on the word uphill gave me the following results:

> *Uphill* [adverb] : towards the top of hill or slope [adjective] : slopping upwards [noun] : An upward slop

So, I'm trying to use it in a sentence like below :

"It was a great time there, and the learning curve has always been uphill"

Meaning to say "It was a great time there, and every time was a positive learning opportunity"

Made a further google search and found following articles:

> The Learning Curve ― The first steps are uphill
>   http://pldata.net/the-learning-curve-%E2%80%95-the-first-steps-are-uphill/
>
> Travel: Europe - It's an uphill learning curve - The Independent
>   http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/travel-europe-its-an-uphill-learning-curve-1177314.html

And in the above articles, **uphill** seems to be used to mean **difficult**, like climbing a hill.

Is it a correct usage of 'uphill' with 'learning curve' to mean it as a **positive learning experience** considering that uphill is **upwards**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to use an adjective [***steep***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/steep) instead of *uphill* as it is more idiomatic when used with the *learning curve*.

> having or being a slope or gradient approaching the perpendicular

[Collins Online Dictionary]

This linked [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uphill+learning+curve%2Csteep+learning+curve%2C&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csteep%20learning%20curve%3B%2Cc0) and [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learning+curve+was+uphill%2Clearning+curve+was+steep&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clearning%20curve%20was%20steep%3B%2Cc0) show *steep learning curve* and *learning curve was steep* are more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

When used figuratively, **uphill** typically implies difficulties:

> Marked by **difficulty or strong resistance**; laborious

([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=uphill))

> **difficult** to do or to achieve

([Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/uphill))

To convey the idea of continuously learning something new, try something like:

> ...and I learned  something new every day

Note: *learning curve* typically collocates with the adjective "steep". A steep learning curve commonly means you need to [learn a lot (or something difficult) in a short period of time](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/learning-curve). However, a diametrically opposite interpretation of ["steep learning curve"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve#.22Steep_learning_curve.22) is possible: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6226/141939

Answer (score 0):

If I extend your usage a little bit:

*It was a great time there, and the learning curve has been always going uphill*

This would mean that no matter how much you tried, there was always a new material to learn, you could not see the top of the hill. So the sentence is suggesting exhaustion which is contrasting great time.